# Access base class super in mixin

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I've got a class structure that looks like this:

```
class Question(object):
    def answer(self):
        return "Base Answer"

class ExclaimMixin(object):
    def answer(self):
        return "{}!".format(super(ExclaimMixin, self).answer())

class ExpressiveQuestion(Question, ExclaimMixin)
    pass
```

I want the `answer` method in `ExclaimMixin` to be able to access `answer` in `Question` when called in `ExpressiveQuestion`, so that it would return `"Base Answer!"`.

Clearly in this case, this can be solved by putting the `answer` method that's in `ExclaimMixin` in `ExpressiveQuestion` instead, but in some cases this isn't possible (more depth and branching in the class structure for example).

Is it possible to achieve this result using mixins, or can it only be done by mangling the base class tree?

Answer (score 5):

With using mixins you need to remember simple rule for base classes order - "right-to-left". That means, all mixins should go **before** actual base class.

```
class Question(object):
    def answer(self):
        return "Base Answer"

class ExclaimMixin(object):
    def answer(self):
        return "{}!".format(super(ExclaimMixin, self).answer())

class ExpressiveQuestion(ExclaimMixin, Question)
    pass

>>> q = ExpressiveQuestion()
>>> q.answer()
'Base Answer!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt this approach be clearer? You define the question content in Question, then the exclaim in the ExclaimMixin which receives a question content which one you want to apply the mixin (something that makes sense) and then in the ExpresiveQuestion you mix both of them.

```
class Question(object):
    def answer(self):
        return "Base Answer"

class ExclaimMixin(object):
    def exclaim(self, answer):
        return "{}!".format(answer)

class ExpressiveQuestion(Question, ExclaimMixin):
    def expresive_question(self):
        return self.exclaim(self.answer())
```

In [1]: from answer import *

In [2]: eq = ExpressiveQuestion()

In [3]: eq.expresive_question()
Out[3]: 'Base Answer!'